# using NEWSEQUENTIALID() with UPDATE Trigger

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, guid, newsequentialid

I am adding a new GUID/Uniqueidentifier column to my table.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD VersionNumber UNIQUEIDENTIFIER UNIQUE NOT NULL DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID()
GO
```

And when ever a record is updated in the table, I would want to update this column "VersionNumber". So I create a new trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [DBO].[TR_TABLE_NAMWE]
ON [DBO].[TABLE_NAME]
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN 
    UPDATE TABLE_NAME
    SET VERSIONNUMBER=NEWSEQUENTIALID()
    FROM TABLE_NAME D
    JOIN INSERTED I ON D.ID=I.ID/* some ID which is used to join*/
END
GO
```

But just realized that NEWSEQUENTIALID() can only be used with `CREATE TABLE` or `ALTER TABLE`. I got this error

```
The newsequentialid() built-in function can only be used in a DEFAULT expression for a column of type 'uniqueidentifier' in a CREATE TABLE or ALTER TABLE statement. It cannot be combined with other operators to form a complex scalar expression.
```

Is there a workaround for this ?

Edit1: Changing `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` to `NEWID()` in the trigger solves this, but I am indexing this column and using `NEWID()` would be sub-optimal

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you say its only available under certain conditions, you could do something nasty like:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (G UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID())
INSERT @T OUTPUT INSERTED.G VALUES (DEFAULT)
```

Does it have to be a GUID? if you use a [`rowversion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) you get the same functionality without needing a trigger as well as better indexing performance.

Comment: +1 it's unfortunate, indeed - but `NewSequentialId()` is only available as a DEFAULT value for a column - seems to be the same in 2008 R2, too :-(

Comment: Microsoft hasn't touched this problem in 8 years; it's abismal.  SSMS 2012 still throws errors about validating the column whenever you try to modify a table that has newsequentialid() as its default.  These workarounds involving creating temporary tables just to get a unique id are unacceptable, although this is probably the best workaround so far.